# How-To select elements from my XML-file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to control the execution of a PowerShell programm by an XML-file.
I started to design the XML-file and it currently looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sequences>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-A</SequenceName>
    <SequenceNumber>01</SequenceNumber>
    <Package>
      <PackageFolder>Package-A</PackageFolder>
      <PackageNumber>01</PackageNumber>
    </Package>
    <Package>
      <PackageFolder>Package-B</PackageFolder>
      <PackageNumber>02</PackageNumber>
    </Package>
  </Sequence>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-B</SequenceName>
    <SequenceNumber>02</SequenceNumber>
    <Package>
      <PackageFolder>Package-C</PackageFolder>
      <PackageNumber>01</PackageNumber>
    </Package>
    <Package>
      <PackageFolder>Package-D</PackageFolder>
      <PackageNumber>02</PackageNumber>
    </Package>
  </Sequence>
</Sequences>
```

In PoSh I read-in this XML by:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path "PathToMyXmlFile"
```

I can get an object-like view by using the following code-line:

```
$xml.Sequences.GetEnumerator()
```

Screenshot of Command-Output:

[image: Screenshot of Command-Output]

At the moment I do not get any further, because I don't know how to select a node in my XML. For example I want to get the "PackageFolder" Package-A or the "PackageNumber" of Package-A. ($xml.Sequences."Sequence-A"...)

How to select those elements correctly?
Is the design of the XML not usable for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PowerShell Data Basics: XML](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-data-basics-xml/) gives a good overview on accessing XML nodes. Basically, you have 2 ways of accessing the nodes, directly, or using XPATH.

Starting by loading your data:

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sequences>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-A</SequenceName>
    <SequenceNumber>01</SequenceNumber>
    <Package>
      <PackageFolder>Package-A</PackageFolder>
      <PackageNumber>01</PackageNumber>
    </Package>
    <Package>
      <PackageFolder>Package-B</PackageFolder>
      <PackageNumber>02</PackageNumber>
    </Package>
  </Sequence>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-B</SequenceName>
    <SequenceNumber>02</SequenceNumber>
    <Package>
      <PackageFolder>Package-C</PackageFolder>
      <PackageNumber>01</PackageNumber>
    </Package>
    <Package>
      <PackageFolder>Package-D</PackageFolder>
      <PackageNumber>02</PackageNumber>
    </Package>
  </Sequence>
</Sequences>
"@
```

Directly, involves needing to either directly access, or iterate through the nodes, e.g.:

```
PS C:\> $xml.Sequences.Sequence[0].Package[0]

PackageFolder PackageNumber
------------- -------------
Package-A     01
```

This means you have to know the order. The "Better" way is to iterate through the objects:

```
PS C:\> $SeqA = $xml.Sequences.Sequence | Where-Object { $_.SequenceName -eq "Sequence-A" }
PS C:\> $SeqA

SequenceName SequenceNumber Package
------------ -------------- -------
Sequence-A   01             {Package, Package}

PS C:\> $SeqA.Package | Where-Object { $_.PackageFolder -eq "Package-A" }

PackageFolder PackageNumber
------------- -------------
Package-A     01
```

Or the oneliner:

```
($xml.Sequences.Sequence | Where-Object { $_.SequenceName -eq "Sequence-A" }).Package | Where-Object { $_.PackageFolder -eq "Package-A" }
```

The second approach is to use XPATH, where you gain some flexibility for searching at the cost of ease of use:

```
$xml.SelectSingleNode("//Sequences/Sequence[contains(SequenceName, 'Sequence-A')]/Package[contains(PackageFolder, 'Package-A')]")
```

It all depends on how you want to use the object.

Comment: It looks complicated at the moment and I will have to determine, if I can and want to go this way in my project.
Your answer definitively takes me a step further and I will mark it as "answer". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An easy select-xml example.

```
(select-xml /Sequences/Sequence/Package file.xml).node

PackageFolder PackageNumber
------------- -------------
Package-A     01
Package-B     02
Package-C     01
Package-D     02
```

This gives you the same thing:

```
$xml.Sequences.Sequence.Package
```